# XSLT: Count only when value greater than nul

Tags: xslt-1.0

All,

This question is related to XSLT 1.0

Is there a way to only count nodes where a specific value is greater than null?
I use the sum function to get the total of this:

```
<servicelevels>
    <servicelevel>
        <key>0..20</key>
        <value>100.00</value>
    </servicelevel>
    <servicelevel>
        <key>20..30</key>
        <value>0.00</value>
    </servicelevel>
    <servicelevel>
        <key>30..40</key>
        <value>0.00</value>
    </servicelevel>
    <servicelevel>
        <key>40..50</key>
        <value>0.00</value>
    </servicelevel>
    <servicelevel>
        <key>50..60</key>
        <value>0.00</value>
    </servicelevel>
    <servicelevel>
        <key>60..70</key>
        <value>0.00</value>
    </servicelevel>
    <servicelevel>
        <key>70+</key>
        <value>98.33</value>
    </servicelevel>
</servicelevels>
```

To find the sum of the value keys, I use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(servicelevels/servicelevel/value | servicelevels/servicelevel/value)"/>
```

what produces the sum of 198.33 to calculate the the average of the 7 nodes I use the  `xsl:value-of select="count(....)"`  what calculates it as 28.333 but I only want to find the average for the nodes that contain the actual values what in this example are just 2 nodes what creates an average of 99.165.

Is there another (relative simple) way of achieving this?

The XML always contains the 7 key values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select only `value` nodes with content (as number) greater zero:

```
<xsl:variable name="values" select="servicelevels/servicelevel/value[number(.) &gt; 0]"/>
```

Average:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum($values) div count($values)"/>
```